# Is a question of why a particular historical site is named in a given way when translated to English on topic?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

The question is pretty much summarized by the title. I'm in Vietnam, and a particular historical site is consistently called a particular thing when referred to in English. I'm trying to figure out *why* it's called that. Is such a question on topic?

---

Specifically, I'm trying to find out why the "Purple Forbidden City" in the Imperial City, Huế ([link to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_City,_Hu%E1%BA%BF)), is called "purple". I just don't know if I should be asking here, or if maybe I should try the "Linguistics" SE.

Comment: I'm just the janitor here, but it sounds good to me. However, if you really want to try your luck on another stack, the English stack would probably be a better choice than Linguistics. Etymology questions there tend to get a good response.

Comment: I've gone ahead and asked the question: http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/28358/why-is-hues-purple-forbidden-city-so-called